# Smooth structure of embedded submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Here is a rather long quotation from "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by J. Lee.

> *Proposition 5.2* (Images of Embeddings as Submanifolds). Suppose $M$ is a
>   smooth manifold with or without boundary, $N$ is a smooth manifold, and
>   $F: N \to M$ is a smooth embedding. Let $S = F(N)$. With the subspace
>   topology, $S$ is a topological manifold, and it has a unique smooth
>   structure making it into an embedded submanifold of $M$ with the
>   property that $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.
>
> *Proof*. If we give $S$ the subspace topology that it inherits from $M$,
>   then the assumption that $F$ is an embedding means that $F$ can be
>   considered as a homeomorphism from $N$ onto $S$, and thus $S$ is a
>   topological manifold. We give S a smooth structure by taking the
>   smooth charts to be those of the form $(F(U), \phi \circ F^{-1})$, where $(U, \phi)$
>   is any smooth chart for $N$; smooth compatibility of these charts
>   follows immediately from the smooth compatibility of the
>   corresponding charts for $N$. With this smooth structure on $S$, the map
>   $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image (essentially by definition), and
>   **this is obviously the only smooth structure with this property.** ...

My question is about the bold sentence. He says that it is obvious, but it is not obvious to me. Why is the constructed smooth structure the *only* smooth structure that makes $F$ a diffeomorphism between $N$ and $S$?

Comment: If $\widetilde S$ represents the topological manifold $S$ endowed with _some_ smooth structure such that $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, then for any smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ for $N$, it follows that $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{-1})$ will be a smooth chart for $\widetilde S$ because $F(U)$ is open in $S$ and $\phi\circ F^{-1}$ is a composition of diffeomorphisms. So the unknown smooth structure on $S$ must be the one determined by these charts.

Comment: @JackLee I didn't expect a response from the author! Thank you very much.  Now I understand it.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\widetilde S$ represents the topological manifold $S$ endowed with some smooth structure such that $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, then for any smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ for $N$, it follows that $(F(U),\phi\circ F^{−1})$ will be a smooth chart for $\widetilde S$ because $F(U)$ is open in $S$ and $\phi\circ F^{-1}$ is a composition of diffeomorphisms. So the unknown smooth structure on $S$ must be the one determined by these charts.